# Tkinter 'Canvas object has no attribute createtext' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ive just been starting out on the Tkinter module. Ive been trying to make a pop-up box that displays some text. Everytime i run it this error pops up:

```
Canvas object has no attribute 'createtext'
```

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from datetime import date, datetime
root= Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='black')
c.pack()
c.createtext(100, 50, anchor=w, fill='red', font='Arial 28 bold underline', text='Final Countdown')
```

Comment: why do you think it has a method with that name? Have you tried reading some documentation to see a list of available methods?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Which name? Also i got it from a Python beginners book

Comment: If that's what the book is telling you, you need to get a different book. That's a glaring typo. The method name is `create_text`.